# Origin of VIC-II (PAL) chip labelled 8656R2?

Tags: commodore-64

Wondering why a C64 VIC chip (fully functional) that I got off eBay had an 8565R2 label fitted on top of it:
[image: MOS 8565R2]

I peeled it off to find this:
[image: MOS 8656R2]

I haven't ever heard of a VIC-II (PAL) labelled MOS 8656R2. What is this - a mistake in the naming of a production run, or some variant other than the [generally known versions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOS_Technology_VIC-II#List_of_VIC-II_versions)?

(Note: The C64 Reloaded2 board that I tested it in does detect it as an 8565.)

Comment: Got a picture of the sticker as well?

Comment: Updated to include picture of sticker as well.

Comment: Now that's interesting. One guess: Typo when setting up the stamping :))

Comment: Related: https://www.forum64.de/index.php?thread/6414-vic-8656r2/

Comment: Seems [courtesy of Google Translate :)] like a mis-labelled production run is also what the forum64 commenters find most likely. Interestingly, the date code and even the silver sticker itself is identical to mine.

Comment: If this was an ebay purchase from China, quite a few chips are now getting shipped essentially repackaged/refreshed, with old engravings ground off and new pins fitted. The new engravings are sometimes an approximation of the originals. If you're really unlucky, the silicon inside is not even a close approximation of the original.

Comment: @scruss Yes, there are increasingly counterfeits in circulation, especially the C64 SID is a risky purchase since it's even rarer. I'd never attempt a purchase of these outside Europe (not that this is any guarantee). In this particular case, the seller was German and the VIC does seem to be fully functioning (tested various demos pushing it). Only the labelleing is off.

Comment: Here's another stickered one, same date code, UK seller: https://www.ebay.com/itm/273972880172 Probably same story. Impulse bought it, so we'll see... ^^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Other people](https://www.forum64.de/index.php?thread/6414-vic-8656r2/) have observed this chip in the wild, and it seems like the consensus is that these chips are from a mislabelled 8565 production run, where the stamping text has accidentally swapped the 5 and 6 digit occurances.